# How to print json value using jquery

Tags: jquery, json

```
[  
   Object   {  
      id: "1",
      name: "sakthivel"
   },
   Object   {  
      id: "2",
      name: "sathish"
   },
   Object   {  
      id: "3",
      name: "saravanan"
   },
   Object   {  
      id: "4",
      name: "murugan"
   },
   Object   {  
      id: "5",
      name: "velmurugan"
   },
   Object   {  
      id: "6",
      name: "vadivelan"
   }
]
```

Comment: Your JSON is **Invalid**.

Comment: var json = (function () {
            var json = null;
            $.ajax({
                'async': false,
                'global': false,
                'url': "http://localhost/download/index.php/home/getarray",
                'dataType': "json",
                'success': function (data) {
                    json = data;
                }
            });
            return json;
        })(); 
        
        console.log(json);

Comment: Updated answer. Take a look Sakthivel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) as mentioned below:

```
var json = '{"value":"validJSON"}';
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
console.log(json);
```

---

Full snippet:

```
var json = (function() {
    var json = null;
    $.ajax({
        'async': false,
        'global': false,
        'url': "localhost/download/index.php/home/getarray";,
        'dataType': "json",
        'success': function(data) {
            var parsed_result = JSON.parse(data);  //parsing here
            return parsed_result; //return when data is parsed successfully
        }
    });
})();
console.log(json);
```